# what is num_routing_shards in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Shard to which the search or index request needs to be done is decided by below formula

```
routing_factor = num_routing_shards / num_primary_shards
shard_num = (hash(_routing) % num_routing_shards) / routing_factor
```

I am not able to understand usefulness of num_routing_shards. I have read about this in below links but not able to understand this and what is splitting.

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/indices-split-index.html#indices-split-index
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-the-index-number-of-routing-shards-setting-how-can-i-calculate-it-based-on-the-number-of-shards/297540
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-are-number-of-routing-shards/120506

It would be very helpful if someone explain this

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand, I will try to explain it.

1. **if no split process is on going**, the routing formular is:

   ```
   shard = hash(_routing) % num_primary_shards
   ```

   we use the formular to decide which shard a document request (for example, index, delete, update) is sent to.
2. The split index API allows you to split an existing index into a new
   index.

   For example, you have an index with 5 primary shards
   (index.number_of_shards: 5) , and you want to distribute you data
   more evenly on 20 nodes. As primary shards nubmer cannot be changed
   after creating index , you have to reindex your data to a new index
   (for example, index.number_of_shards: 10). Elasticsearch provides
   the split index API to do it.
3. **In the split process**, we use the following formula to decide how a doucment is send to the new shard in the new index.

   ```
   routing_factor = num_routing_shards / num_primary_shards
   shard_num = (hash(_routing) % num_routing_shards) / routing_factor
   ```

   index.number_of_routing_shards used with index.number_of_shards to
   route documents to a primary shard.

   For example, you set num_routing_shards to 30, and you want to
   change index.number_of_shards to 10 (5 -> 10). hash(_routing) of a
   doucment is 10003.

   routing_factor(3) = 30 / 10

   shard_num(4) = (1003 % 30) / 3

   Finally, the doucment will be send to the shard(4) in the new index.
4. See, the larger num_routing_shards is set, the distribution is more
   evenly in the new index. You can take num_routing_shards as a
   virtual shard number in the reindex processing.

   To make sure routing_factor is a valid number. num_routing_shards
   must be times of num_primary_shards.

Comment: I am still not able to understand the importance of num_routing_shards. It would be helpful if you provide the example that we can achieve something special with num_routing_shards that can't be achieved via only num_primary_shards